# Conditions for multivariate limit $\displaystyle\lim_{u\rightarrow 0} \frac{u^{\top} B u}{\|u\|}$ to exists.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (set of $n\times n$ real matrices). What are the necessary and sufficient (or at the very least sufficient only) conditions on the matrix $B$ (which does not depend on $u$) for the following multivariate limit to exists?

$$\displaystyle\lim_{u\rightarrow 0} \frac{u^{\top} B u}{\|u\|}$$

where $\|u\|= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} u_i^2}$.

**ATTEMPT:** I have not approached the problem in a delta-epsilon approach but rather via intuition. Similar to how $x^2 \leq x$ for all $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \tfrac{x^2}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x = 0$, as a quadratic form, $u^{\top}Bu$ is of one order higher in powers compared to $\|u\|\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}|u_i|$ with $u=(u_1,\ldots,u_n)^{\top}$. Thus my intuition dictates that, as $u\rightarrow 0$, the numerator converges to $0$ much faster than $\|u\|$. However, if this idea is true, I don't know how to formalize it in proof.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is always $0$. $ |\frac{u^{\top} B u}{\|u\|}|\leq \frac {\|u\|\|B\|\|u\|}{\|u\|}=\|u\|\|B\|<\epsilon$ whenever $\|u\|<\frac {\epsilon}{\|B\|}$.